# Having issues with blended shader

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, shaders

I was killing time making a lowpoly version of a trashcan that a kitbash with online parts but I wanted to make around the handles transparent using a alpha texture but, my issue is that or a blend the transparent part or de principle shader.
[image: Only the handles are visible]

Comment: Try setting transparent color to black?

Comment: try using the transmission of the principled shader

Answer (score 1):

change the shader's blending mode (from Opaque to Alpha Blend or Alpa Cliping in case you want to have more control on its threshold)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a idiot, I just realize that I did not paint all the alpha , so of course the black part will be transparent but now I have a question, Why if a leave in alpha blend the normals seems inverted ._.

[image]